# Python in Usermode linux

Tags: python, c, linux, user-mode-linux

so I managed to use Python in helloworld C program.

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(){
printf("This is C\n");
Py_Initialize();
PyRunSimpleString("print('this is python')");
Py_Finalize();
return 1;}
```

I had to `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and python3-dev as well. Just in case.

To compile and run this I used following commands:

```
gcc -c $(python2.7-config --cflags) cprog.c
gcc cprog.o $(/usr/bin/python2.7-config --ldflags)
./a.out
```

Everything works so far. Now I have user-mode-linux from [git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git](http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/)

I need to be able to use Python from `arch/um/drivers/ubd_kern.c`.
But when I as much as even insert the `#include <Python.h>` and try to compile everything with `make V=1 ARCH=um` it fails.

It appears that usermode linux has a `-nostdinc` flag. So I tried to link the Python.h file and added `CFLAGS_ubd_kern.o := -DTEST77 -I/home/alli/pyhack $(shell python2.7-config --cflags)` to `arch/um/drivers/Makefile` but then the compilation results in multiple conflicts.

How can I use Python from user-mode-linux's drivers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python needs a full C library support. I've ported Python 2.5 to run in my kernel user-mode with newlibc, so it can be done, but nevertheless it neds complete C library in the process